# Redshift Python UDFs Import on Every Function Call

Tags: python, user-defined-functions, amazon-redshift

I'm starting to learn Python User-Defined Functions in Redshift and I have a couple of questions that I would need clarifications on. Assuming that I have defined the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_parse_url_query_string(url VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS varchar(max)
STABLE
AS $$
    from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qsl
    import json
    return json.dumps(dict(parse_qsl(urlparse(url)[4])))
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Is this going to run the `imports` every time that the function is called or is this compiled by Redshift and just imported a single time?

My second question is whether there is a way to return a variable data type. For example, if I wanted to create a function that grabs the value of nested json fields, the result could be anything from a string to an integer or a boolean. Is there someway to create an autodetect on the function return type?

Answer (score 1):

**Execution**

Yes, the `import` will execute every time.

One way to avoid this is to use `IMMUTABLE` as the volatility of the function. This allows Redshift to cache the output of the function for the given input value, avoiding the need to run the Python function in future for the same input value.

**Return value**

**The data type of the return value is fixed and cannot be changed.** A different return value can be defined for a different function name or a different input type (eg define one function that takes in an integer and returns an integer, and then another function with the same name but a string input type that returns a string as output).

Also, it would be very difficult to use a function that returns a different output data type -- the SQL statement that calls the UDF would be wanting a specific data type, not one that changes.

Answer (score 1):

**Imports**

Yes and no. Redshift reuses udf execution environments within statements (perhaps even within whole transactions but I haven't tested). While it's true that the import statement is processed every time the function is invoked in handling that import statement cpython quickly checks to see if the module has already been imported and uses the already imported module if it has. Function-local (late) imports like these are frequently used to get around circular dependency problems and thus kind of have to be performant. I've also used this to work around the lack of global initialization in udf's by doing something like the following:

`if '_cache' not in globals():
    import thing
    globals()['_cache'] = thing.build_cache()
return _cache.get(arg)`

It's not something I'd do anywhere but a udf but this isn't exactly general-purpose code.

Regarding udf execution environment it's obviously impl-detail and should not be relied too heavily upon but realistically it's unlikely to change substantially any time soon. There are no guarantees about how long-lived any particular process will be / how many rows it will process but it's in their interest to keep them around for as long as they can as cpython process (and container) creation is not exactly cheap - certainly too heavy to do for each single row. They rely on lxc for isolation and give you a real (if sandboxed) linux environment in which to execute (which is really necessary for user-installed native extensions if you think about it). There's even some documentation lying around on the filesystem for those who care to dig :)

**Return value**

While it's true the data type of the return value cannot be changed redshift (now?) supports the [ANYELEMENT](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-data-types.html) datatype for both arguments and return types. As described by the previous answer it still requires a disambiguating typed argument as return-type polymorphism is still not supported, but it does at least save you the trouble of having to create separate functions for every type you want to return.